# What is stringWritableConverter used for

Tags: apache-spark

There are a couple of implicit conversions defined for basic types to their Writable counterpart in `SparkContext.scala`,such as `Int,Long,String`.

Take String for example, there are two definitions defined as below:

```scala
  implicit def stringWritableConverter(): WritableConverter[String] =
    simpleWritableConverter[String, Text](_.toString)
```

And

```scala
  implicit val stringWritableConverterFn: () => WritableConverter[String] =
    () => simpleWritableConverter[String, Text](_.toString)
```

I would ask how these method and variable are used. They are used for implicit type conversion, but there is no input argument for them(`stringWritableConverter` takes no argument, and also `stringWritableConverterFn`).

How does these implicit conversion is to be converted to `WritableConverter`

There are no argument for them, I just can't get how/when these conversions are used

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

To better illustate the problem with code, I write following simple code to minic the spark stuff

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

trait Writable

class IntWritable(value: Int) extends Writable

class Text(value: String) extends Writable

class WritableConverter[T](
                            val writableClass: ClassTag[T] => Class[_ <: Writable],
                            val convert: Writable => T)

object implicit_test {

  private def simpleWritableConverter[T, W <: Writable : ClassTag](convert: W => T)
  : WritableConverter[T] = {
    println("Hello, simpleWritableConverter")
    val wClass = classTag[W].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[W]]
    new WritableConverter[T](_ => wClass, x => convert(x.asInstanceOf[W]))
  }

  implicit val stringWritableConverterFn: () => WritableConverter[String] = {
    println("Hello  stringWritableConverterFn")
    () => simpleWritableConverter[String, Text](_.toString)
  }

  implicit def stringWritableConverter(): WritableConverter[String] = {
    println("Hello  stringWritableConverter")
    simpleWritableConverter[String, Text](_.toString)
  }


  def do_convert(a: String) = println(s"a is $a")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //Compile Error: Required String, Found Text
    do_convert(new Text("abc"))
  }

}
```

When I call the `do_convert(new Text("abc"))`, the compiler complains that `Required String, Found Text`,which means implicit conversion doesn't take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand 100% of the story here, but I feel I might have some useful insights to bring you. I'll be using Spark version 3.4.1 source code (and corresponding Hadoop version 3.3.4) for this explanation.

The full story looks a bit more like [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6b1ff22dde1ead51cbf370be6e48a802daae58b6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L3128-L3218):

```scala
/**
 * A class encapsulating how to convert some type `T` from `Writable`. It stores both the `Writable`
 * class corresponding to `T` (e.g. `IntWritable` for `Int`) and a function for doing the
 * conversion.
 * The getter for the writable class takes a `ClassTag[T]` in case this is a generic object
 * that doesn't know the type of `T` when it is created. This sounds strange but is necessary to
 * support converting subclasses of `Writable` to themselves (`writableWritableConverter()`).
 */
private[spark] class WritableConverter[T](
    val writableClass: ClassTag[T] => Class[_ <: Writable],
    val convert: Writable => T)
  extends Serializable

object WritableConverter {

  // Helper objects for converting common types to Writable
  private[spark] def simpleWritableConverter[T, W <: Writable: ClassTag](convert: W => T)
  : WritableConverter[T] = {
    val wClass = classTag[W].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[W]]
    new WritableConverter[T](_ => wClass, x => convert(x.asInstanceOf[W]))
  }

  // The following implicit functions were in SparkContext before 1.3 and users had to
  // `import SparkContext._` to enable them. Now we move them here to make the compiler find
  // them automatically. However, we still keep the old functions in SparkContext for backward
  // compatibility and forward to the following functions directly.

  // The following implicit declarations have been added on top of the very similar ones
  // below in order to enable compatibility with Scala 2.12. Scala 2.12 deprecates eta
  // expansion of zero-arg methods and thus won't match a no-arg method where it expects
  // an implicit that is a function of no args.

  ...

  implicit val stringWritableConverterFn: () => WritableConverter[String] =
    () => simpleWritableConverter[String, Text](_.toString)
  
  ...

  // These implicits remain included for backwards-compatibility. They fulfill the
  // same role as those above.

  ...

  implicit def stringWritableConverter(): WritableConverter[String] =
    simpleWritableConverter[String, Text](_.toString)

  ...
}
```

#### What are these Writable objects?

I'll quote a part of [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32518079/15405732) here:

> As we already know, data needs to be transmitted between different nodes in a distributed computing environment. This requires serialization and deserialization of data to convert the data that is in structured format to byte stream and vice-versa. Hadoop therefore uses simple and efficient serialization protocol to serialize data between map and reduce phase and these are called Writable(s). Some of the examples of writables as already mentioned before are IntWritable, LongWritable, BooleanWritable and FloatWritable.

So we know we will be bouncing onto a bunch of these `Writable` objects when using Hadoop. In order to do our trusty calculations using primitive types, we need to have a way to go from a `Writable` to our primitives.

#### Why do we seem to have 2 of these `stringWritableConverter`?

If you look closely to the code comments in the bit I pasted here, you'll see that `stringWritableConverter` and `stringWritableConverterFn` do exactly the same thing. `stringWritableConverter` is only there for backwards compatibility.

So we can simplify our problem: only `stringWritableConverterFn` matters here.

#### What happens with this `stringWritableConverterFn`?

In Scala, implicits are resolved at compile time. So at compile time, the following will be called:

```
simpleWritableConverter[String, Text](_.toString)
```

Pay close attention to the types here `[String, Text]`. `String` is the primitive type, `Text` is the `Writable` class [`org.apache.hadoop.io.Text`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/rel/release-3.3.4/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.java).

Let's have a look at the `simpleWritableConverter` function in isolation:

```scala
  private[spark] def simpleWritableConverter[T, W <: Writable: ClassTag](convert: W => T)
  : WritableConverter[T] = {
    val wClass = classTag[W].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[W]]
    new WritableConverter[T](_ => wClass, x => convert(x.asInstanceOf[W]))
  }
```

So, a new `WritableConverter` object is created that stores 2 things:

- the Writable class
- the `convert` function, whose signature is `W => T`. This is the [`toString`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/a585a73c3e02ac62350c136643a5e7f6095a3dbb/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.java#L273-L284) method of `Text` in Hadoop.

#### Conclusion

In Hadoop, Writable classes are used ubiquitously. If we want to be able to retrieve the primitive types they represent, we need to be able to convert those classes to their primitive types. That is what these `WritableConverter` objects are used for.

In the end, we created this `WritableConverter[String]` class that contains a way to convert a `Text` Writable to a `String` primitive through that `toString` method!

#### Answer to your update

If you want to see this converter in action, you can see a [test example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6b1ff22dde1ead51cbf370be6e48a802daae58b6/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContextSuite.scala#L94-L108):

```scala
  test("BytesWritable implicit conversion is correct") {
    // Regression test for SPARK-3121
    val bytesWritable = new BytesWritable()
    val inputArray = (1 to 10).map(_.toByte).toArray
    bytesWritable.set(inputArray, 0, 10)
    bytesWritable.set(inputArray, 0, 5)

    val converter = WritableConverter.bytesWritableConverter()
    val byteArray = converter.convert(bytesWritable)
    assert(byteArray.length === 5)

    bytesWritable.set(inputArray, 0, 0)
    val byteArray2 = converter.convert(bytesWritable)
    assert(byteArray2.length === 0)
  }
```

In here, you see that we create this `converter` object that is able to do the conversion for you using its `convert` method (from the `WritableConverter[T]` class in the start of this post).

The difference with your example is that you're not calling the `convert` method of the `WritableConverter`. So Scala can't find any function that converts a `Text` into a `String`.

Comment: Thanks @koedlt for the great answer. I know the Hadoop Writable and Spark primitive things, for example, The place that needs this: `SparkContext.sequenceFile and SequenceFileRDDFunctions.saveAsSequenceFile`.  What I want to know is, eg, when `SequenceFileRDDFunctions.saveAsSequenceFile` is called, how spark or scala knows which implicit convertion should  be used,because, the implicit function/value I mentioned in the question takes no argument, thanks!

Comment: Basically, I thought the implicit function should take the form like : Int =>IntWritable, but the implicit function takes the form ()=>WritableConverter[Int], I just can't get what's going on behind the scene

Comment: The form `() => WritableConverter[String]` just means: out of nothing, we will create a `WriteableConverter[String]` at compile time. And that is also what happens as I explained it in my post. This has no input. The conversion is that `toString` method, which is a Writable => String conversion.

Comment: So the creation of that converter object happens implicitly, but the conversion itself (`toString`) is not an implicit function.

Comment: Thanks @koedit for the helpful answer, I still quite get the point, I write a simple code in the `Update` section of the question. Could you please help take a look what the problem and how to fix it,thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer to give you some more info w.r.t. your update :)

Comment: I look through the spark source code,and find an implicit defintion in RDD,`  implicit def rddToSequenceFileRDDFunctions[K, V](rdd: RDD[(K, V)])
      (implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V],
                keyWritableFactory: WritableFactory[K],
                valueWritableFactory: WritableFactory[V])
    : SequenceFileRDDFunctions[K, V] `. With this definition, I really get out how the implicit works now..